# How can I give NULL bytes in input?

Tags: reverse-engineering, bash

I am trying to exploit a binary(64-bit) with gadget chaining technique. I have to pass the address
 `0x00007ffff7e10cf8`
which holds the code for
 `pop rax;ret`
On passing this input in little-endian format, my bash issues a warning saying :
 `bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`
and prints only till 7f ignoring the NULL bytes.

To make sure that I got the concept right that bash IGNORES and does not stop parsing on encountering the first NULL byte. I tried `echo $(printf "\x00\x55\x44\x33\x22\x00\x34")`and the output was

```
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
UD3"4
```

So yes, bash simply ignores the NULL bytes and keeps parsing till the end.

Is there a  way to actually pass in NULL bytes in bash? I am using bash version 5.0.3

Comment: How do you have to pass the address, as an argument or as stdin? As far as I know there is no way to pass a null byte as an argument in bash. According to [this site](https://eklitzke.org/unexpected-places-you-can-and-cant-use-null-bytes) (and some others) it's not even possible to receive an argument containing null for any program.

Comment: Shell variables cannot store null bytes, because they store null-terminated strings. Your only option is to write such values directly to the standard input of some process.

Comment: `printf "\x00\55\x44\x33\x22\x00\x34"`, though, works fine, because the *shell* never sees any null bytes; `printf` converts `\x00` *internally* and writes a null byte to standard output.

Comment: @Socowi, I need to pass it as command-line argument. But if this is not possible that I can do it via stdin. I have the source code and I will take input from stdin.

Comment: When you can edit the program, I would rather write a small parser instead of reading stdin so that you can supply text arguments to your program `yourProg  00007ffff7e10cf8` that way you don't have to deal with escape sequences in bash and can feed more than one address into your program. Parsing a hex string argument and converting it into its numerical representation should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shell script is not really the recommended way to patch binary files. However, it can be done with `dd`. Say, you have to write `0x00007ffff7e10cf8` at positions `0xff00-0xff07` of a file, overwriting the bytes which are already there (counting starts from 0). You can use

```
#!/bin/bash

input='original.bin'
output='patched.bin'
patch='\x00\x00\x7f\xff\xf7\xe1\x0c\xf8' # Keep an eye on endianness!
start="$((16#FF00))"

{ 
  dd if="$input" bs="$start" count=1 2>/dev/null
  printf "$patch"
  dd if="$input" bs="$((start+${#patch}/4))" skip=1 2>/dev/null
} >"$output"
```